# How to reference System Assigned Identity in Bicep when deploying Key Vault Access Policy

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

For a project I want to deploy three related resources to Azure through Bicep templates: 1) App Service with System Assigned Managed Identity, 2) Key Vault and 3) Access policy for the App Service (step 1) to the Key Vault (step 2).

The AppService deployment outputs the `principalId` of the System Assigned Identity which is then later on used when deploying the KeyVaultAccessPolicy.

However, when I run the AZ CLI (`az deployment sub create --location WestEurope --template-file ./main.bicep --parameters ./parameters/parameters-dev.json`)
to deploy this to Azure I get the following error:

```
'The language expression property 'outputs' doesn't exist, available properties are 'templateHash, parameters, mode, provisioningState, timestamp, duration, correlationId, providers, dependencies, outputResources'.
```

Does anyone have an idea why referencing the `principalId` of the App Service does not work here? Many thanks for any help.

#### Modules and main.bicep:

**main.bicep**

```
module appService 'modules/appService.bicep' = {
  name:  'deployAppService'
  scope: resourceGroup(appServiceResourceGroup)
  params: {
    name: appServiceName
    location: appServiceLocation
    alwaysOn: appServiceAlwaysOn
    apimIpAddress: appServiceApimIpAddress
    appServicePlanResourceGroup: appServicePlanResourceGroup
    appServicePlanName: appServicePlanName
  }
}

module keyVault 'modules/keyVault.bicep' = {
  name: 'deployKeyVault'
  scope: resourceGroup(appServiceResourceGroup)
  params: {
    name: keyVaultName
    dependsOn: [ appService ]
    location: appServiceLocation
  }
}

module keyVaultAccessPolicy 'modules/keyVaultAccessPolicy.bicep' = {
  name: 'deployKeyVaultAccessPolicy'
  scope: resourceGroup(appServiceResourceGroup)
  params: {
    name: '${appServiceName}-ap'
    dependsOn: [ keyVault ]
    objectId: appService.outputs.appServiceManagedIdentity
  }
}
```

**appService.bicep**

```
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-12-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: '${subscription().id}/resourceGroups/${appServicePlanResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/${appServicePlanName}'
    enabled: true
  }
}

output appServiceManagedIdentity string = appService.identity.principalId
```

**keyVault.bicep**

```
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  dependsOn: dependsOn
  properties: {
    enabledForDeployment: true
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: true
    enabledForDiskEncryption: true
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    accessPolicies: []
    sku: {
      name: 'standard'
      family: 'A'
    }
  }
}
```

**keyVaultAccessPolicy.bicep**

```
resource keyVaultAccessPolicy 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2022-07-01' = {
  name: name
  dependsOn: dependsOn
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
        objectId: objectId
        permissions: {
          secrets: [
            'get'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already found the answer:

1. I missed that modules already contain an `dependsOn` property and so there is no need to pass the dependencies as `param`.
2. The KeyVaultAccessPolicy's name did not contain a reference to the parent resource (KeyVault), see `name: '${keyVaultName}/add'` below

See working modules and main.bicep below:

**main.bicep**

```
module appService 'modules/appService.bicep' = {
  name:  'deployAppService'
  scope: resourceGroup(appServiceResourceGroup)
  params: {
    name: appServiceName
    location: appServiceLocation
    alwaysOn: appServiceAlwaysOn
    apimIpAddress: appServiceApimIpAddress
    appServicePlanResourceGroup: appServicePlanResourceGroup
    appServicePlanName: appServicePlanName
  }
}

module keyVault 'modules/keyVault.bicep' = {
  scope: resourceGroup(appServiceResourceGroup)
  name: 'keyVaultDeploy'
  params: {
    location: appServiceLocation
    name: keyVaultName
  }
}

module keyVaultAccessPolicy 'modules/keyVaultAccessPolicy.bicep' = {
  scope: resourceGroup(appServiceResourceGroup)
  name: 'keyVaultAccessPolicyDeploy'
  dependsOn: [
    keyVault
  ]
  params: {
    keyVaultName: keyVaultName
    objectId: appService.outputs.appServiceManagedIdentity
  }
}
```

**appService.bicep**

```
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-12-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    // left out 
  }
}

output appServiceManagedIdentity string = appService.identity.principalId
```

**keyVault.bicep**

```
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  properties: {
    enabledForDeployment: true
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: true
    enabledForDiskEncryption: true
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    accessPolicies: []
    sku: {
      name: 'standard'
      family: 'A'
    }
  }
}
```

**keyVaultAccessPolicy.bicep**

```
resource keyVaultAccessPolicy 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2022-07-01' = {
  name: '${keyVaultName}/add'
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
        objectId: objectId
        permissions: {
          secrets: [
            'get'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for a heads up you don't need to pass these stuffs with parameters.

Just use the existing tag with the scope it will be easier to get datafrom any resource.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/existing-resource#different-scope